# Crystal Reports: Formula unable to display as whole numbers

Tags: string, crystal-reports, concatenation, formula, inventory-management

I am using the following formula:

```
If {USAGE.CURFY} = 0 
then "" 
else {USAGE.CURFY} & " (" & ({USAGE.CURFY_DAYSREMAINING} * 
{USAGE.USEDPERDAY})+{USAGE.CURFY} & ")"
```

I am having difficulty displaying the formula with the numbers as whole numbers. I keep getting decimals with two places. I can make it appear as round numbers using File, Options, Fields, Number... but when I upload it to our Crystal Server, the two decimal places show again.

So, I am under the impression that I need to round within the formula.

USEDPERDAY and CURFY_DAYSREMAINING are fields with decimal values. CURFY is a whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the numbers to strings:

```
if {USAGE.CURFY} = 0 then "" 
else totext({USAGE.CURFY},0) 
 & " (" & totext({USAGE.CURFY_DAYSREMAINING} * {USAGE.USEDPERDAY} + {USAGE.CURFY},0) & ")"
```

The second parameter to `totext()` specifies the number of decimals.

Comment: Thank you. I think I was thrown off because I had the parenthesis for the multiplication portion which made me unsure if I could use ToText function on it.